# How to filter irregular data on elasticsearch with logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok

I'm just learning to use elastic and I have a log like this.

```
*************************************************************************************
Task with ID = 119 is waiting for the message to arrive on the queue 1294598175.
=>bpc_wait_for_event (comm_utils.c)
=>bpc_select (pipe_utils.c)
Using select() to wait for an event to occur at 10:00:02 
Event selector just had 1 fd(s) triggered at 10:00:02 
=>process_incoming_data (tcp_main.c)
=>reset_device_idle_timers (tcp_main.c)
=>receive_incoming_message (tcp_xfer.c)
=>receive_ncr_message (tcp_xfer.c)
=>tcp_receive_data (tcp_xfer.c)
=>bpc_sock_recv (comm_utils.c)
=>tcp_receive_data (tcp_xfer.c)
=>bpc_sock_recv (comm_utils.c)
30.32.31.30.46.33.33.38.34.30.30.39.38.41.38.31       0210F33840098A81
38.34.30.30.30.30.30.30.30.30.30.30.30.34.30.30       8400000000000400
30.30.30.34.31.36.36.30.33.34.39.34.38.38.31.31       0004166034948811
30.34.31.32.37.33.30.31.31.30.30.30.30.30.30.30       0412730110000000
33.30.30.30.30.30.30.30.30.32.32.34.31.30.30.30       3000000002241000
30.31.30.30.30.30.30.30.30.30.34.31.36.39.34.39       0100000000416949
31.30.30.30.30.31.30.32.32.34.36.30.31.31.30.31       1000010224601101
38.31.30.30.31.31.30.32.31.34.30.36.34.35.30.30       8100110214064500
30.35.30.30.39.39.33.37.20.20.20.20.20.20.30.30       05009937      00
53.31.47.39.39.38.32.36.30.31.32.46.54.32.30.30       S1G99826012FT200
35.35.4B.52.58.56.44.33.36.30.30.32.30.31.30.30       55KRXVD360020100
32.33.36.30.43.30.30.30.30.36.30.35.31.36.34.39       2360C00006051649
36.31.30.37.31.30.38.39.38.31.33.33.39.30.30.33       6107108981339003
34.35.31                                              451             
Received 211 bytes of data from device #600, sending to CROUTer
=>raw_msgx2sv_msg (tag_utils.c)

    ************************ Header Fields *************************
    orgdev:     600             utrnno:     0
    orgid:      0               reversal:   0
    destid:     0               repeat:     0
    last_task_id:   119             fintran:    0
    msgtype:    51              phase:      0
    task_msgtype:   0               balances:   0
    respreq:    0               stood_in_for:   0
    resp_qid:   -1              issuer_posted:  0
    smsgno:     0               sv_trace:   0
    nwindicator:    0               timestamp:  0
    devinfo:    []
    hpan:       []
    fld_flags:  00000000000000000000
    sys_msg_no: 0

msgsnd_w_retry [dst task: COMMSINT, time: 24/02/2020 10:00:02.0468]: Msg sent to queue 1293844488
```

I've tried using the filter I created but it doesn't work and just inserts every single line into the elastic like this.

[The Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRvAe.png)

And this is the logstash file

```
input {
beats {
    port => "5044"
} } filter {    ruby {    code =>  "  event.set('msgfilter', event.get('message').scan(/\s{7}[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?=\r\n|\s*\r\nReceived)/) ) "       id => "ruby-counter"
 }
   # merge array of strings
   mutate { join => { "msgfilter" => "" }  }
   # remove spaces
   mutate { gsub => [ "msgfilter", " " , "" ] } } output {
elasticsearch {
    hosts => [ "localhost:9200" ]
} }
```

I want the result looks like this, I want to take the red box part and combined it into one line.
[Result I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X52gn.png)

Answer (score 0):

you may try to extract all the bytes with this regex:

`^(?:[\dA-F]{2}\.?){1,} {7,}([\w\s]{1,16})$`